# swift subview does not full-fill parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift3

When app starts, I use this method to set the root view controller.

```
func showRootViewController() {
    let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainViewController = sb.instantiateInitialViewController()!
    self.window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

In main view controller, I've code to set the view to container view

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if(userManager.hasRegistered()) {
            let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
            self.setContentViewController(sb.instantiateInitialViewController()!)
        } else {
            let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Registration", bundle: nil)
            self.setContentViewController(sb.instantiateInitialViewController()!)
        }

    }

    func setContentViewController(_ contentViewController: UIViewController) {
        print(self.containerView.frame)
        let contentView = contentViewController.view!
        contentView.frame = self.containerView.bounds
        self.containerView.addSubview(contentView)
    }
}
```

Let look at the view, I have container view what is used to add subviews. I set the background to help everyone address the frame of container view
[image: main view]

The subview is designed as below:
[image: result design]

The result is not as my expected. ContainerView has gone somewhere (I really don't know), the subview is move on the top.
[image: result view]

Please help me.

Answer (score 7):

contentView frame is setted in the wrong position.
You should move this line of code:

```
contentView.frame = self.containerView.bounds
```

in

```
override func func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    contentView.frame = self.containerView.bounds
}
```

Comment: the result is still same. viewDidLayoutSubviews is even run before viewDidAppear.

Comment: try to read this : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @iGeno. The key is missing add child view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on dimensions in viewDidLoad.
Try viewDidLayoutSubviews instead. Be aware that it can be called multiple times
I have solved this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

i used a tableview with a single row(your subview)to wrap content